# how to create traceable widgets with functions (python, tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently trying to create the GUI with tkinter for a very specific data processing tool. The user will load a file via a button and depending on that data the tool will display a number of dropdown-menues to choose options specific to the provided data. 
Right now I am stuck on creating those widgets after initializing the mainloop (I need to initialize/ update them after the fact, because the user should also be able to load several files). The widgets are being displayed, though I cannot access their value, because that is a local variable inside the function.

TLDR: I want to create and update tkinter widgets after initializing the window and its values need to be accessible

I tried writing a function as seen below, which would trigger depending on other code. Sadly, the values they provide do only reflect the value of the widget (in this case the dropdown) at the termination of the function and do not change with the widget.
Changing them to global variables didn't fix the updating-problem either.
I looked into different ways to create widgets after the fact, but do not seem to find a way.

```
import tkinter as tki

root = tki.Tk()
root.title('Data Comparison')

#specifying a frame and its grid
frame = tki.Frame(root)
frame.grid(column=9, row=7)

#I'm working with dicts, not lists, because that more accurately represents my
#actual data
numbers= {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':4} 
colors= {'blue':5, 'red':6, 'green':7, 'orange':8, 'pink':9, 'yellow':10}

def createDropdown():
    global DDvalue
    DDvalue = tki.StringVar(root)
    DDvalue.set(list(numbers)[0]) 
    global DDvalues
    DDvalues = tki.OptionMenu(frame, DDvalue, *numbers)
    DDvalues.grid(column= 7, row = 1)
#the global variables only display the accurate value at the time of creation of the widget
createDropdown()

def displayvalue():
    print(str(DDvalue.get()))

DDvalue.trace_add('write', displayvalue())

def updateDropdown():
    DDvalues.destroy

btnupdate= tki.Button(frame, text='update', command= updateDropdown)
btnupdate.grid (column= 8, row= 7)

#I also could not delete the widget with the button above

root.mainloop()
```

Right now the trace_add only prints the value once, at the creation of the widget (one), afterwards, changing the value results in this error message: 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Also, the update button is not capable of accessing the widget

I would like to see the values of a widget created after meeting certain conditions to be accessible.

Comment: This `.trace_add('write', displayvalue())` should writen as `.trace_add('write', displayvalue)`, **note without `()`** and `global DDvalue` **must be** `global`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment!When I delete the variable after global I get an invalid syntax error. Also, when I drop the empty parentheses, I get the following error: 
TypeError: displayvalue() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: You have `#global DDvalue` as `comment`, i mean must be `global DDvalue`.

Comment: I tried that as stated in the description. I'll edit the code to include it.

Comment: Change `def displayvalue():` to `def displayvalue(*args):`.

Comment: I don't understand why you expect the options in the `Optionmenu` to change.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Sadly, it is only secondary to my problem.

Comment: @Goyo the options will not change, but the value chosen by the user (I admit, value and valueS are kind of similar, my bad). I want to trace that choice

Comment: Well that does change. And the `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` is because you should pass a function to `.trace_add` instead of its return value, as already explained in another comment. And the `TypeError: displayvalue() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given` is because `displayvalue` needs to take 3 parameters as the error message itself says (and another comment too). So what is your primary problem?

Comment: thanks for your patience! The errors got resolved, and I understand why they happened now.

My primary problem is that I would like to change the contents of an OptionMenu by tracing another button. My idea was to use functions to do this, since trace_add() only takes functions. If that part does not work out, I am happy to use another way to change the contents of the OptionMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`destroy()` needs parens to be called.

`displayvalue` is passed as a function object, and should not have parens.

`trace` passes two arguments on top of the variable it is called on: the last is the `mode`, which corresponds to what action triggers the callback (`write`, `read`, or `unset`).

The naming of functions, and variables is quite important to be able to read and understand code.

You should first declare and assign your variables; declaring them global inside a function, before they are created is quite bad practice.

tkinter is usually aliased as `tk`, not `tki`

```
import tkinter as tk


numbers= {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4} 
colors= {'blue': 5, 'red': 6, 'green': 7, 'orange': 8, 'pink': 9, 'yellow': 10}


def set_value():    
    dd_var.set(list(numbers)[0]) 


def displayvalue(*args):
    # this is triggered each time dd_var is reset to a value
    print(args)
    print(str(dd_var.get()))


def remove_dropdown():
    drop_values.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Data Comparison')

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(column=9, row=7)

dd_var = tk.StringVar(root)
set_value()
dd_var.trace_add('write', displayvalue)

drop_values = tk.OptionMenu(frame, dd_var, *numbers)
drop_values.grid(column=7, row =1)

remove_dropdown_btn = tk.Button(frame, text='update', command=remove_dropdown)
remove_dropdown_btn.grid (column= 8, row= 7)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I know that declaring global variables from inside a function is bad practice, however I don't know how to change a OptionMenu from inside a function, that is why I just declared it there. Is there a way to declare an OptionMenu  globally and change it later by a function or something similar that is callable by a button?